# Cannot open explorer windows with shortcut when cmd.exe is running

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, windows-explorer

If cmd.exe is running (on Windows XP), and I try to open a explorer window by using the shortcut Windows+E, the window does not pop up. It pops up after the cmd.exe window is closed.

This does not happen when I start the explorer from Start/Run or from another cmd.exe prompt.

How can I open an explorer with the shortcut without closing cmd.exe?

Comment: Need you to clarify something please. Do so by editing your post.

Does this also happen when you try the Win+E key combination after removing focus from the cmd.exe window? (for instance, after clicking on the desktop?)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and seems to work fine:

Went to Start > *Run.....* (Or you can hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) > typed `cmd.exe` > that was the main window, hit <kbd>WIN</kbd> and worked fine.

Comment: It does not work at my computer at home and at my computer in the office.

Comment: I agree : this behavior is not normal for XP.

Comment: Just tried it a few different ways after ticking and unticking the likely looking boxes in the properties of the cmd window, and had no problem opening Explorer with Win+E, even with the command window running full screen.

Comment: Download CCleaner and do the registry fix and see if that fix's your problem

Comment: Just be very very careful with what you clear out. Don't do it if you haven't a good understanding of the registry.

Comment: You can do backups of the registry before you clear it up, if you make an error then double click on the backup, restart, its all back to normal